# How to use slickGoTo in typescript in Angular 4

Tags: angular, slick.js

I have side menu with hide/show button. This menu is included in a another component containing Slick as Slider. Once I hide the side menu the slick is deformed. I should run SlickGoTo(index) so that the slick should be initialized.

what I tried now is to created a listen event on the button and use the action on the ts of the component where the slick is included.

Here is my source code:

```
this.globals.buttonState.subscribe(value => {
           // here i should run slickGoTo(0) for the slick
         });
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I don't really understand what is not working ? It that the subscribe that is not called ? Do you have any errors ?

Comment: @e666 subscribe is working but how to use slickGoTo on the slick once i click a button is my problem. the button is on the side menu ( a compoenent  included in the slick component)

Comment: You will need to share more code for help. Example: where is declared you slick slider, where is your button. See here to create example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve